# Lombok post @Builder build event

Tags: java, lombok

I am using lombok builder. I want to do following:
Once a user create an object using `build()` function. I want to fire following methods defined in class.

1. Validate
2. Initialize some internal object.

What is the way to achieve this?

Comment: With bare hands... I don't understand what you are asking. Lombok generates code (standard one, not specific one) and you want specific code (if I understand well). Maybe what you need is to "delombok" (there are plugins to do that) your class and do what you want in `build` (or use a `build` proxy). As is your question is too broad/unclear

Comment: @RC. I can't see anything unclear here. The OP wants Lombok to do all the work as usual, just with a small tweak. Similar requests are rather common. It's not very different from e.g. `@ToString(exclude="boringField")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such feature, but there's a [related feature request](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/674), which applies to constructors and setters, rather than the builder. I guess, it should work for you, however, it's not implemented yet.